# GeneratePDF service failed to start in Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: adobe, livecycle, lcds

Not able to start service "GeneratePDF" through Admin UI. Getting following error

ALC-AAC-0017-000: Service(s) failed to start. It could be configuration problem.

Please suggest if there is a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a fresh installation of LiveCycle ? Did the service work before ? If its a fresh install, then review the environment configuration to see if any steps were missed.

If the service worked before, I would recommend connecting to the server using LiveCycle Workbench and start the service using the components Tab. If the service starts there, you are good to go. Otherwise you need to check the server logs to see a valid reason for it.

Thanks,
Armaghan.